# Translation of "church planting" vocabulary

Tags: traducción, religión

In Protestant circles, the process of starting a new church is often referred to as "planting." I haven't found a translation for this in dictionaries I've looked in, and haven't really heard a parallel Spanish concept. What Spanish terms would be most commonly used to translate the following:

- *to plant a church* (the verb describing an individual or church starting a new church)
- *church plant* (the noun describing the newly-started church)
- *church planter* (an individual in charge of starting a new church)
- *church planting* (the process of starting new churches)

Comment: Is this new church part of another church or group? Do you use it in any religious context, or just in protestant or catholic ones? I was thinking that maybe it has relation with the protestant community, as in Catholic or Orthodox denomination the churches are usually build by decision of a higher hierarchy.

Comment: with church do you refer to the building or to the community?

Comment: @JoulSauron: Good point, edited. I've heard it in a Protestant context, but used whether it's an individual starting a church on their own or a large denomination or organization responsible for starting it.

Comment: @Javi: Primarily the community of people gathered together as a church, regardless of the place they happen to be meeting together.

Comment: @jrdioko Then I guess we have to wait for a Spanish speaker Protestant, as in the Catholic Church this is not common. Most of the Spanish-speaking community is Catholic compared to Protestant, maybe that's why "church planting" is not heard. [Here is some data](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protestantismo#Protestantismo_en_Latinoam.C3.A9rica).

Comment: @JoulSauron: Makes sense. Out of curiosity, what do Catholics call new churches and the process of starting them?

Comment: @jrdioko Well, the thing is that I see it works quite different, I don't think even I understand what you mean. For example, in a town there are churches in different neighbours, and your community is the church of your neighbour. And only the Catholic Church or a religious order can start a new church, not an individual, unless it's in aan area without any other church, for example, in missions, and I guess under permission from the Catholic Church.

Comment: @jrdioko [check this wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_planting#Practical_objections).

Comment: If you're talking about the community of people I guess an more or less accurate translation would be "establecer una nueva comunidad" in Spanish when you say church usually we think of cult buildings more than of the community gathering there even if "Iglesia" means both in Spanish as well as in English.

Comment: @Laura if you read the discussion, is not about Spanish or English, the point is the use in the Protestant context, that's why in Spain is not heard. I was confirmed this phenomenon by Protestant Spanish-speakers from Latin America, and they use mainly "plantar".

Answer (score 3):

Courses on church planting are generally entitled "Plantamiento de Iglesias."

Comment: Bienvenida a Spanish.SE!

Comment: Thanks, welcome to the site! What would "church plant" and "church planter" be then?

Answer (score 2):

In this context, I would translate to plant as *instaurar*.

> to plant a church: *instaurar una iglesia*
>
> church planter: *el instaurador de la iglesia*
>
> church planting: *la instauración de iglesias*

But I suspect anglicisms like *plantamiento* and *plantador* will prevail.

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to find anything of the sort in online dictionaries but I did a quick google search and I did find several articles in Spanish that talked about expanding the protestant church and they all did mention the word "plantar" which would be the literal translation of "to plant".

As an example here is one of the sentences:

> También destacó la plenaria sobre la necesidad de **"plantar"** nuevas
>   iglesias...